# Does Google Chrome's DNS settings override Windows' DNS settings (or vice versa)?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, dns

If I change Google Chrome's DNS settings (under Settings > Privacy and Security), does it override Windows' DNS settings (or vice versa)? If I've already set Windows to use a specific DNS, will Chrome respect it? Or do I still need to set it in Chrome?

Google Chrome DNS settings: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSBBJ.png)
Windows 10 DNS settings: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkMsz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about specifically is DNS over HTTPS, a newer, more secure protocol.

Windows 10 began supporting DNS over HTTPS (DoH) in the Windows 10 2004 build (May 2020 Update). It is off by default and it currently requires a registry change and cannot be changed from the UI. The UI option was added in recent insider/preview versions of Windows 10 and should be available in the 21H2 update being released this month. Until then, DoH can be enabled in Windows 10 by modifying the registry. Create a new DWORD `EnableAutoDoh` with a value of `2` in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters` then restart Windows.

[image]

Next, to use DoH you need to modify your Windows DNS settings so that you are using one of the supported DoH DNS servers, such as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1).

In regards to Google Chrome, it has supported DoH experimentally since version 78 and is on by default in version 83 and newer, unless it is operating in a managed (active directory domain) environment. However, it does require that your operating system is configured with a DNS server that supports DoH.

To answer your question, Chrome will attempt to use DoH at all times via the OS's configured DNS servers, if they support it. Otherwise, you can override your operating system's DNS servers by specifically configuring the Secure DNS options in Google Chrome. If your operating system is configured to properly use DoH then all applications, including Google Chrome should use DoH.

Comment: great, thanks for the info!

Comment: Have two 10 Pro machines on 21H2 now.... not seeing the updated UI in settings panel, nor the regkey. Perhaps they didn't include it in 21H2 after all ?